# Retrieve values as per index of another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am facing an issue in this since a long.

- **Problem:**

I need to get value as per the index of following array in my tableView.

```
indexArray = [3, 6, 4, 5, 8, 30, 31, 7, 18, 29, 1]

paramNameArray = ["Date", "Sync Time", "UUC2T7", "Set MD", "Total KVA", "Total KW", "Running MD", "SMS 1 KW", "P.F.", "ET-5 KW", "ET-3_4 KW", "ET- 6_7 KW", "ABP-1 KW", "ABP-1A KW", "ABP-2 KW", "G-22 KW", "UUC36T37", "G-23 KW", "WRM KW", "Total KWH", "Total KVAH", "ET-5 KWH", "ET-3_4 KWH", "ET-6_7 KWH", "ABP-1 KWH", "ABP-1A KWH", "ABP-2 KWH", "SMS 1 KWH", "UUC60T73", "PLC Time", "Voltage", "Current", "Load Factor", "Avg. P.F."]
```

**Problem:**

- Now in cellForRowAt indexPath of my tableView, I need "Set MD" value at indexPath 0 (need value as per the index of indexArray)

This way for each row of my tableView, I need value as per the indexArray's index.

**For Example:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    (at 0th Index) cell.lblParameter.text = "Set MD"  // value from paramNameArray as per indexArray's index(3)

    (at 1st Index) cell.lblParameter.text = "Running MD"  // value from paramNameArray as per indexArray's index(6) 

    // And so on...

    return cell
}
```

Help would be much appreciated, Thanks! :)

Comment: `cell.lblParameter.text = paramNameArray[indexArray[indexPath.row]]`

Comment: @vacawama, I can't believe it was so simple. Thank you so much man!

Comment: You should rethink your data structures. This has a code smell and you're going to end up with a crashing app.

Comment: @AshleyMills, Sorry for my English. But I can't understand what you said.

Comment: Have you given any thought to what would happen if the first array contained a value that wasn't a valid index in your second array? (it would crash)

Comment: @AshleyMills, Thanks, I like the way you showed the consequences here. But, that was already handled by the server side developers. It was programmed as first array will contain only those indexes that have valid values in second array :)

Comment: Good luck with that!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get an index from the `indexArray` using index path in `cellForRowAt:` method. and then using that index (got from `indexArray`) you get value from `paramNameArray`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let index = indexArray[indexPath.row] as! Int

//check that index won't exceeds `paramNameArray.count` otherwise it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

  if index < paramNameArray.count {

    let text = paramNameArray[index]
    cell.lblParameter.text = text
  } else {
     cell.lblParameter.text = "some default text goes here in case if value is not present"
  }

  return cell
}
```